# Refresh IconTabFilter count after Navigation in view in SAPUI5

Tags: odata, sapui5

In my SAPUI5 application, I am facing a an issue with the refresh. There are multiple views like Orders, OrderInfo, OrderChange, OrderClose.

In the first view Orders, I have IconTabFilter to filter different types of Orders and I am using setCount to show the number in the IconTab Filter.

The problem is when I am on screen OrderClose where I close my order and I come back to the main view Orders using navigation, it shows me 1 order less but the IconTabFilter count does not change unless I do model.refresh() and model.UpdateBinding().

Ideally i want the count to change the moment I come to the view Orders from view OrderClose with updated count.

Can anyone help me out ?

BR
Nilesh

Answer (score -1):

Re-rendering control will solve this issue,instead of refreshing model or bindings.

Invoke [`rerender`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Element.html#rerender) on control to be updated.

> This triggers immediate rerendering of its parent and thus of itself and its children.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your answer. It is somehow not working. 

Can you tell me the right place to put it. AN example may be ???

Following is the structure of my controller

onInit: function() { ........ }, 

_handlRouteMatched : function()
{ 
this.doRefresh(); 
}, 

doRefresh:function()
{  
this.getView().byId('IconTabFilterid'); 
this.getView().byId('Tableid');  
},
 
onAfterRendering: function()
{
 this.setCountForFilters();
}

setCountForFilters: function()
{
..........
}

Comment: `doRefresh` would be the right place to re-render, if it still doesn't work then I believe updating binding will only help! Have look at [this](https://scn.sap.com/thread/3529837) post.